# Error when applying createPositionLine in trading view api vanilla js

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

handsome guys
I have an error using the createPositionLine() function because I want to display the value of the position I have taken in attaching the trading view in the vanilla js environment. Error Name:

## Uncaught (in prompt) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createPointset')

## at L.createPointset

```
        widget.onChartReady(function() {
            widget.chart().createPositionLine()
                .onModify(function() {
                    this.setText("onModify called");
                })
                .onReverse("onReverse called", function(text) {
                    this.setText(text);
                })
                .onClose("onClose called", function(text) {
                    this.setText(text);
                })
                .setText("PROFIT: 71.1 (3.31%)")
                .setQuantity("8.235")
                .setPrice(15.5)
                .setExtendLeft(false)
                .setLineStyle(0)
                .setLineLength(25);
        });
```

Comment: Widget.chart() has already been initialized.
Is there anything I need to set the widget separately to use the createPositionLine()?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had mixed up `createPositionLine` and `createPointset` in the error message. In this case, my knowledge isn't enough to help you. (I assume, you don't call `createPointSet` explicitly but it is called automatically.) The last thing I would guess is that calling `createPositionLine` might be too early, before the real data was entered.